# What are all possible permissions taken by apps?

Tags: android, android-permissions, user-permissions

There are two types of app permissions in case of android apps

1. Install time permissions- apps take permission while being installed (run at startup, install shortcuts, run in background etc.)
2. Run time permissions- Users give permission to the app (gallery, camera, contacts etc.)

Can you please give me the separate lists of all the permissions?
Also, how to know which permissions are taken by an app?

Comment: check this out, hope this would help. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission

Answer (score 0):

The complete list of all permissions available to an app is available [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission). For runtime permissions you should search for all permissions in the provided link with the `Protection level` equal to `dangerous`. For example `ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION` is a runtime (dangerous) permission as stated [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION).

If you want to check that a specific permission is granted or not, use the following code snippet:

```
boolean isGranted = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
```

Answer (score -1):

For [permission list](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission) go through [this page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro) do some digging you will find required info

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.